# Awk - how to combine the two commands?

Tags: awk, getline

I use two commands to scan for channels:

```
awk 'BEGIN{while(" w_scan -c PL -x " | getline ) print >> "tmp" }'

awk 'BEGIN{while(" w_scan -I tmp -E 0 -t 3 -F " | getline) print >> "channels" }'
```

I want to do the same, but with one command. How to simplify to skip writing to tmp?

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT:**

I tried this command, but it does not work:

```
awk 'BEGIN { while (" w_scan -c PL -x " | getline ){split($0, tab, RS) system( " w_scan -I \047" tab[1] "\047 -E 0 -t 3 -F " ">>" "channels" )}}'
```

Result error -> [enter link description here](http://wklej.org/id/826192/)

**EDIT-1**

When I use this script does not work.

run.awk

```
BEGIN { 
  while (" w_scan -c PL -x " | getline ) {
    split($0, tab, RS) 
    system( " w_scan -I '\047'" tab[1] "'\047' -E 0 -t 3 -F >> channels" )
  }
}
```

Result error → [enter link description here](http://wklej.org/id/826487/)

When I use this script, it works well.

sh script

```
#!bin/bash
awk 'BEGIN{while(" w_scan -c PL -x " | getline ) print >> "tmp" }'
awk 'BEGIN{while(" w_scan -I tmp -E 0 -t 3 -F " | getline) print >> "channels" }'
```

Result -->  [enter link description here](http://wklej.org/id/826575/)

Comment: Why are you doing this in AWK and not just running it in a pipe in the shell? What is `w_scan`? Will it accept input on `stdin`?

Comment: @ Dennis Williamson In awk I do it for two reasons. 1: for test. 2: Result of the second command will be processed later in awk. W_scan is → `http://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/W_scan` The command `awk 'BEGIN{while(" w_scan -I tmp -E 0 -t 3 -F " | getline) print >> "channels" }'` should file "channels" burnt the result →`http://wklej.org/id/824380/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just stick them both in the `BEGIN` block:

```
awk '
  BEGIN {
    while(" w_scan -c PL -x " | getline ) print >> "tmp"
    while(" w_scan -I tmp -E 0 -t 3 -F " | getline) print >> "channels"
  }
'
```

If you want the whole thing on one line you can separate the commands with semicolon:

```
awk 'BEGIN { while(" w_scan -c PL -x " | getline ) print >> "tmp"; while(" w_scan -I tmp -E 0 -t 3 -F " | getline) print >> "channels" }'
```

#### Edit

You're accessing `tmp` in both loops, make sure it's written before the second loop with `close` and `sync`:

*run.awk*

```awk
BEGIN {
  while(" w_scan -c PL -x " | getline ) 
    print >> "tmp"
  close("tmp")
  system("sync")
  while(" w_scan -I tmp -E 0 -t 3 -F " | getline) 
    print >> "channels"
}
```

Execute with:

```
awk -f run.awk
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it does not work. See the output error --> `http://wklej.org/id/826209/`

Comment: Your first and second example do not match, the second one doesn't really make sense. The problem with the first one seems to be that you're trying to read `tmp` before it's been closed and flushed to disk. Add `close` and `sync` before reading it again. See edit.

Comment: Thor. The last command works very well. Thank you very much for your help.